# Area of a triangle and rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The area of a triangle is $3$ times less than $2$ times the area of a rectangle. If the sum of the two areas is $64$ square meters, what is the area of the triangle and what is the area of the rectangle?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:
Let the area of the triangle be $T$, and the area of the rectangle be $R$.
The information given implies:

- $T = 2 R / 3$
- $T + R = 64$

Answer (score 0):

Because $T=\frac{2R}{3}$ and $T+R=64$, we have that $\frac{2R}{3}+R=64$ and $\frac{5R}{3}=64$ and $5R=192$. Therefore, $R=38.4$ square meters and $T=\frac{2*38.4}{3}$ = $25.2$ square meters.

The area of the triangle is **$25.2$ square meters** and the area of the rectangle is **$38.4$ square meters.**